# Make my containerview (= popup for app) close when clicking a button in xcode 6 swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been searching and searching and I have tried a lot of stuff that I found here at stack overflow but nothing does the job.

When a user goes to a part of my app (View controller) there should popup a small view (view container) with some options (buttons). I added a blur over the normal view controller so the focus is on the container view.
Now how can I easily close this container view after clicking the button?
See picture:
[image]

1. Is there a simple way to do this?
2. If you have a solution please be thorough I am a big iOS noob
3. Should I pick something else in stead of a container view maybe?
4. Thank you for taking the time to read this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you create that box? Is it a UIAlertView? if so you can use:

```
func dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(_ buttonIndex: Int,
                      animated animated: Bool)
```

If it's just a UIView, use:

```
viewName.removeFromSuperView()
```

when the button is clicked. If you post some code I might be able to help further.

Comment: I got those on these pages, by the way, if you want to read more into it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would be nice to have more info it!
Well in stead of an alertview it is a Containerview. Is that like totally the wrong thing to do?
Found that option now! Testing :p

Comment: So I made use of a View in stead of another View controller (which seemed totally useless for this example. Now I am going to experiment with this further. Thanks a lot for helping me out :D